# Change route shape by dragging it

Tags: here-api

I'm looking for an example of a draggable route using the **HERE Maps V3 API**. I want to be able to add waypoints anywhere on the route, not only drag it's start and end points.

On the [API Reference](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/resource-param-type-route-representation-options.html), there is a **RouteRepresentationModeType** called **dragNDrop**, but I have no idea where to start.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle click events on the route line to :

1. add a new waypoint where the user has clicked
2. recompute the route
3. hide the old route and display the new one

Then you can handle drag/drop events on the waypoint and do the recompute on "dragend" event.